# How to enable commenting system in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning how to create custom Wordpress theme from [this page](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/08/how-to-code-a-wordpress-3-0-theme-from-scratch)
and everything is working except commenting system because they haven't described how to enable it (they only used `<?php comment_form(); ?>` to insert form into template). I can see my comment in the backend but not in the page itself (I can see a link showing **1 comment** but when I click it nothing happens). Obviously I need some PHP code to show my comments but have no idea where to start! I am stuck because I just started to learn Theme Development and my PHP knowledge is limited. 
Can anyone give me a suggestion or a solution for that problem? It would a mean a lot to me. 

 My Wordpress page [HERE](http://robertpeic.com/wordpress_template/)
Thank You!!

Comment: This question might be better answered at Stack Overflow's sister site http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is edit the “Page Template” and insert the following code

```
if ((‘open’ == $post-> comment_status)) { comments_template();
```

somewhere in between the following two lines.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  endwhile; endif;
```

also check

[**Enable and Disable Comments**](http://en.support.wordpress.com/enable-disable-comments/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to start with a base theme.  They have all the necessary files and code, but literally nothing else.  You can build your custom theme right into it.  I recommend Bones for this.  You can find it here: [Bones Developer Theme](http://themble.com/bones/).  This is a good option if you have limited PHP or WordPress knowledge as the core stuff needed for a custom theme is already there, basically all you need to do is build your design into it.